# Removing/filter null values, if it contains in the string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is how my code looks, i have a string which is going to fetch the value from db iteratively, if it is not null then it will store it and return the value one by one, but if it is null then also it return the value as null.. Can you help me in this , if i can stop sending the null values and filter it while making a condition in else part.

```
String  str = find_value_from_db(); 

if(StringUtils.IsNotEmpty(str))
{ 
String value = str;
}

return value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem cold but, if you don't want to deal with **null** strings from your database then don't get them from the database when you query it. Use the `IS NOT NULL` condition when building your `SELECT` query string. A simplified example:

```
String sql = "SELECT myTextField FROM myDBTable WHERE myTextField IS NOT NULL;";
```

Regardless of what DB you're querying, pretty much all flavors of SQL have this sort of condition or at least something similar to it..